# logging exceptions in azure with enterprise library

Tags: logging, azure, enterprise-library

> how can we log exceptions in azure with enterprise library 6 . how to
>   create trace.log file. it is creating on local machine but not in
>   azure

Logger.Write("Map Test Exceptioin  ==> "+err, Category.General, Priority.High, 100);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :) in azure we don't have rights on file system so it's not possible to create file on azure or write log in file in azure. so better and easy way is to use azure diagnostics. and write logs on azure BLOB.